# Eclipse MySQL drivers missing from Specify a Driver and Connection Details

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, connection, driver

I'm trying to make a connection to my Database in MySQL. When I go to Database Source Explorer, and there to Database Connection right click and new connection, I click on MySQL, New Driver Definition and nothing… drivers are missing. I use MySQL with Connector/J, Eclipse IDE 2019‑09, MySQL Workbench 8.0. I have Data Tools installed.

Please, somebody, help me. I'm searching for hours and can't find any solution, that works for me.

Comment: can you specify more what you want to reach ?  do you wanna connect your eclipse to your database ? via Database development ?

Comment: Yes @fitDeveloper

Comment: You have add the jar file mysql driver in eclipse.

Comment: check this link. https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Fcon-HowToAddAJDBCDriver.html

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit too late, but I had the same issue as yours, and a simple fix worked for me. I just had to expand the window, and the list was visible. The list was hidden because of the small window size. Sounds odd, but definitely did work for me.

Comment: I feel so stupid for not realizing this sooner... Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

How to add a JDBC driver

This procedure assumes you are creating a new JDBC data source, and you need to install a new driver because the driver that the database requires is not available in the list of drivers.

1 . First select the version of your database : 
[image: eclipse connection database]

2 . second click on JAR List field : 
[image: eclipse connection database]

3 . and : 
[image: eclipse connection database]

4 . remove the default driver 
[image: eclipse connection database]

and finally click OK ! this should work fine

Comment: The problems is that when I go to Select a Driver Template and Definition Name everything is empty…. the drivers doesn't exist.

Comment: you have to download the jar from this link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ then unzip your download file and then click add jar/zip just like  step 2

Comment: I have done that. But I'm unable to click add jar/zip. Don't know why.

Comment: yes because you didn't select which version of MySql  look at my updated answer on step 1

Comment: make sure to select version and type a driver name in 'Name/Type' section before you go to 'Jar List' Section

Comment: I already told, I can't select anything, there are no versions inside. It's empty… you can see only Name/Type.. Jar List.. but the drivers are not inside.

Comment: @xamsas Were you able to find a solution to this? I too am stuck at the same point as you. I do not have anything being listed in the selection of drivers template.